# Which UML relationship is used to connect an instance with its class?

Tags: uml

I have a diagram with classes and objects. Which directed relationship could I use to connect an object with the class of which it is an instance? Is this the realization dependency as shown in the figure below?

[image]

In this figure, the relationship is redundant, because the class name is already mentioned in the object's rectangle behind the colon, but in my project, they use very long class names and I don't want to show those inside the rectangles of all the objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Realize` relation you used is wrong. This is used to show that an interfaces is implemented. Instead use a stereotyped dependency:

[image]

However, since the class is already shown in the name of the instance this is duplication of information (and I'd regard it as superfluous).

Comment: I guess using a non-standardized stereotype is the only way to do it, thanks. One comment: Showing that an interface is implemented by a component is just one example where the realization can be used. According to 7.7.3.4 of UML 2.5: *Realization is a specialized Abstraction dependency between two sets of NamedElements, one representing a specification (the supplier) and the other representing an implementation of that specification (the client). (...)  The meaning of “implementation” is not strictly defined (...).* 
Figure 7.21 shows an example where this dependency connects classes.

Comment: Yes. I did not mean that the `Realize` is only used for what I said, but just that it's wrong (or mis-used) in this context. I guess you could even get by with this mis-use if you have some guidelines along with your model that explain its use. But the dependency is better suited, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a relationship. You're showing that MyOldBMW is an instance of *Car with: MyOldBMW:Car*.

Besides, MyOldBMW should be written in camelCase: *myOldBMW:Car* (the first letter in lowercase).

Comment: I know, but does UML have a particular representation of the "instance of" relationship as a line connecting class and object? I have very long class names and I don't want to repeat that class name for each instance of the class.

Comment: With regard to your statement that MyOldBMW should be written in camelCase: Usually, I do that, although to my knowledge, the UML specification does not prescribe it. It only prescribes that classifiers should begin with an uppercase character.

Answer (score 1):

According to the UML specifications you cannot leave out the name of the classifier.

UML v2.5 §9.8.4 on Instance Notation says:

> An InstanceSpecification is depicted using similar notation to its
>   classifiers, but in place of the Classifier name appears an underlined
>   concatenation of the instance name (if any), a colon (‘:’) and the
>   Classifier name or names. The convention for showing multiple
>   classifiers is to separate their names by commas.

So while it is not wrong (although redundant) to use a `Dependency` (not a `Realization`) to visualize the relation between the `Classifier` and the `Instance`, it *seems* wrong to leave out the Classifier Name from the Instance Notation based on this paragraph.

As pointed out by www.admiraalit.nl, the specs unfortunately leave room for discussion by not explicitly defining the notation grammar for `InstanceSpecifications`

A further paragraph in the same chapter reads:

> NOTE. Names are optional for Classifiers and InstanceSpecifications.
>   The absence of a name in a diagram does not necessarily reflect its
>   absence in the underlying model.

Which is not 100% clear to me. Yes, Classifiers and Instances can have empty names, but does this statement mean we can leave out the name of the `Classifier` from the `InstanceSpecification`?

And the grammar defined for `Nested InstanceSpecifications` seems to suggest we are allowed to leave the `ClassifierName` out

> `{<name> [‘/’ <rolename>] | ‘/’ <rolename>} [‘:’ <classifiername> [‘,’<classifiername>]*]`

My suggestion would be to leave the `Classifier` name in to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: The same paragraph says: *Names are optional for Classifiers and InstanceSpecifications. The absence of a name in a diagram does not necessarily reflect its absence in the underlying model.* An underlined colon is enough! See also the BNF for a nested instance (same paragraph), where the classifier name is specified as optional as well.

Comment: You might have a point, unfortunately there is again room for discussion. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The note you cite only tells that in diagrams the name can be left out (be hidden) like you can hide many other things in diagrams. And yes, you can hide the classifier like everything in a diagram. EA isn't a proof for the correctness of this statement, but you can create an unclassified object with just it's name. Makes sense esp. in an analysis phase.